# Reading a file line-by-line

Tags: python

I am trying to read an input file and match the line which contains "ToolVersionEdit" and then split based on "=" and get the second part..I am using the below..am not getting the desired output..where am I going wrong?input and expected ouput are given below

INPUT:

```
[BuildRequest]
BuildRequestVersion=4.4.21
BuildRequestType=Phone
BuildCommandComboBox=common/build/build.sh tz:A8064AAAAANAAT140029.1 tz_bid=AAAAANAA wcnss:A8064AAAAANAAW120072.1 wcnss_bid=SCAQBAF lpass:A8064AAAAANAZL140106.1 boot_9x15:M9615ACETRMAAB12171.1 boot_9x15_bid=ACEHRMAA rpm:A8064AAAAANAAR1100153.1 rpm_bid=AAAAANAAR modem_9x15:M9615ACEFWTAAM4010223.1 modem_9x15_bid=ACEFWTAA apps_9x15:M9615AFEHRMAA2745.1 apps_9x15_bid=AFEHRMAA rpm_9x15:M9615ACETRMAAR1100159.4 rpm_9x15_bid=AAAAANAAR boot:A8064AAAAANAAB12171.1 boot_bid=AAAAANAA lpass_9x15:M9615ACETRMAZL140105.3 apps:A8064AAAAANLGA2214074.1 dsps:A8064AAAAANAAS150007.1 dsps_bid=DSPSBLD
ToolVersionEdit=1.6.21
CheckSumCheckBox=0
PurposeEdit=
[BuildRequestComments]
LineCount=0
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-1.6.21

```
import re
import sys
file = "C:\Dropbox\Reference.brf"

lines = open(file ,'r').readlines()

for line in lines:
    if 'ToolVersionEdit' in line:
        line = line.strip('=')[1]

print line
```

Comment: No need for `readlines`. You can simply iterate over each line in the file using the loop construct you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are overwriting the `line` variable. You're using the same variable as your looping variable as what you're trying to cache. Also, you don't need to continue the loop once you've found what you're looking for.

Another change I made was to remove the call to `readlines`. You can iterate over all the lines directly from the file object. Also, it's bad form to (potentially) overwrite the `file` module with a variable, so I renamed that one too.

```
import re
import sys
filename = "C:\Dropbox\Reference.brf"
try:
    input_file = open(filename ,'r')
except IOError as exc:
    print exc
else:
    cached_line = ""
    for line in input_file:
        if 'ToolVersionEdit' in line:
            cached_line = line.split('=')[1]
            break

    print cached_line
```

Comment: @breden- thanks..also..how to add an exception in-case while the file open fails?

Comment: added exception handling. For future reference, find out what exceptions are thrown by the function in question, then use http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Use ConfigParser. Construction of your file is unix config file and ConfigParser (configparser in python3) can read and parse it http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html.

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser as Parser

filename = 'yourfile.conf'

config = Parser()
config.read(filename)
print config.get('BuildRequest', 'ToolVersionEdit')
```

if you want you can get all options by this code:

```
for section in config.sections():
    for option, value in config.items(section):
        print value
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `split` instead of `strip`

Comment: @Matt- Thanks...how to add an exception in-case while the file open fails?

Comment: see Brendan's answer, looks like his answer covers everything

Answer (score 1):

You need actually two  things.

1. Change `strip` to `split`
2. `break` after you split it.

Resultant code looks like this,

```
 7  for line in lines:
 8      if 'ToolVersionEdit' in line:
 9          line = line.split('=')[1]
10          break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import re
    import sys
    file = "/tmp/abc.txt"

    lines = open(file ,'r').readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if 'ToolVersionEdit' in line:
            desired_line = line.split('=')[1]
```

print desired_line